# MFC child (WS_CHILD) dialog has different style than parent

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have 2 dialog and I´m trying to embedded one to another. It is accomplished by setting style of embedded dialog to WS_CHILD. It works correctly, but embedded dialog has wrong (default windows) style. Is it windows thing, that cannot be changed, or is there any way to fix it? I tried to changed all options for both dialogs in resource editor, but none seems to work.

Main dialog is normal modal dialog.
Embedded dialog is created in `OnInitDialog()` of main dialog like

```
CDialog m_dlg1;
m_dlg1.Create(CDialog1::IDD, this);
m_dlg1.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOMOVE)
```

and has `Style` set to `Child` in `Resource editor`.

Result looks like

[image: current style]

How I want it to look (it looks like it with popup and overlapped style)

[image: wanted style]

Thanks in advance for any help, or recommendations.

Comment: It seems you just need to [enable visual styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175(v=vs.85).aspx) for your application.

Comment: What does happen if you change the Border style to other things in the Resource Editor?

Comment: By the way this is bad UI design! When I looked to it,it seemed to be a modal window on the top of the back window!

Comment: It is a Windows 10 thing, it cannot be changed.  They gave up on trying to keep the visual styles renderer compatible, you can only get the legacy Win7 look.  Do consider getting ahead by removing the border.

Comment: Ok, It is as @HansPassant said. When I open any theme editor, edited Windows theme looks like that embedded dialog. So that "bad" dialog is in correct theme and main dialog is somehow hacked by Win10 to match its special theme :-D Please post it as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @sergiol I know, I wanted to modify that style on runtime to look slightly different than main window.