# CDialog: Why SetParent(this) change the visual Style?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

[image: without SetParent]
[image: with SetParant(this)]

I create a Non modal `CDialog` in a `CView` derived class `m_wndTestDlg.Create(CTestDlg::IDD, this);` and Show/Hide and move the Dialog with the following code

h File:

```
class CTestView : public CView
{
    :
    CTestDlg m_wndTestDlg;
    :
}
```

cpp File:

```
void CTestView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();
    m_wndTestDlg.Create(CTestDlg::IDD, this);
}

void CTestView::OnDialog1()
{
    BOOL b = m_wndTestDlg.IsWindowVisible();
    if (b)
      m_wndTestDlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    else {
      m_wndTestDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
   // if (!m_wndTestDlg.IsWindowVisible()) {    // still not viewable, outside ParentScreen, move to top of CView
        m_wndTestDlg.SetParent(this);
        m_wndTestDlg.SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
}
```

I don't understand why `SetParent` change the visual style to the old WinXP style?

Comment: Does the app have [visual styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do not want to disable Dialog visual style here accidentally with SetParent (this)

Comment: Then you must have a different problem than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064782/mfc-child-ws-child-dialog-has-different-style-than-parent). A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Comment: @dxlv Thanks for the link, No, this is the same problem. SetParent(this) make CDialog as a child of CView. Someone commented there: It is a Windows 10 thing, it cannot be changed. They gave up on trying to keep the visual styles renderer compatible, you can only get the legacy Win7 look.

Comment: Or maybe this [last comment](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3691#issuecomment-732538552) will materialize someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ulterior motive for `SetParent` is to keep the dialog in front of the view then the following might work (or it might not, depending on UI specifics). If, however, the reason is to clip the dialog to the parent view, then this won't help, though it still attempts to explain why.

Main issue here is an inconsistency in how Windows applies visual styles to (descendents of) child windows, or rather does *not* do that. The issue is not confined to VC++ or MFC, and has been noted [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44064782/mfc-child-ws-child-dialog-has-different-style-than-parent), [[2]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/34b29567-28a1-4aeb-97d2-d1476ba856f5/mdi-child-window-appearance?forum=vcgeneral), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610613/why-arent-my-mdi-child-forms-showing-a-shadow), [[4]](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3691) (the last link is an open case on dotnet/winforms but also references [MFC](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/3691#issuecomment-669238507)). Because of this issue, re-parenting the dialog as a child of the view "loses" the theming.

One additional complication here is that the window in question is a dialog, and dialogs are [owned windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#owned-windows). Just calling `SetParent` changes the parent of the dialog, but leaves the owner in place. This goes against the rule that [A window can have a parent or an owner but not both](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100315-00/?p=14613). Also, [`SetParent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setparent#remarks) requires that the style bits be updated to remove `WS_POPUP` and add `WS_CHILD` instead. However, neither clearing the owner nor fixing the style bits changes the styling behavior once the dialog is made a child of the view.

The alternative is to change the *owner* of the dialog, instead of its parent, in which case the visual styles do in fact get applied. This keeps the dialog in front of its owner in the Z order, though it does not clip it to the owner area. The caveat, however, is that the owner must be a popup or overlapped window, so it cannot be set to the view itself, which is a child window, but instead to its closest popup/overlapped ancestor. In UIs with a single top-level window, this often means the one and only main window.

Sample code is below, with some comments inlined, and the `#if 0` part that's *not* working.

```
void CTestView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CView::OnInitialUpdate();

    // dialog gets created with parent = desktop window
    //                          owner  = app main window
    m_wndTestDlg.Create(IDD_ABOUTBOX, this);

    // visual styles *are* applied at this point
    m_wndTestDlg.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}

void CTestView::OnDialog1()
{
    if (m_wndTestDlg.IsWindowVisible())
    {   m_wndTestDlg.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE); }
    else
    {
#if 0 // visual styles *not* applied to test dialog
    // the following make re-parenting consistent with the rules
    // but visual styles are still not applied
    //  ::SetWindowLongPtr(m_wndTestDlg.m_hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, NULL);
    //  m_wndTestDlg.ModifyStyle(WS_POPUP | WS_CHILD, WS_CHILD);
        m_wndTestDlg.SetParent(this);
#else // visual styles *are* applied to test dialog
    // for an owned window, the following sets the owner, not the parent
    // the new owner must be ws_popup or ws_overlapped, thus ga_root
        ::SetWindowLongPtr(m_wndTestDlg.m_hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, (LONG_PTR)::GetAncestor(m_hWnd, GA_ROOT));
#endif
        m_wndTestDlg.SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTop, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this explains the question. However this does not solve my issue. I use multiple Views for a Document, and each modeless Dialog is associated to the specific view, So it is mandatory here that each Dialog is a child to the parent View..

Comment: Use a CDockablePane with embeded CTestDlg?

Comment: @TomTom Problem is that dialogs are owned windows, and cannot *also* be child windows. You can still have them manage their own position in the Z order by handling the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message, in order to keep each dialog on top of its associated view.

Comment: I have tried to manage it with `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`. It is fiddly and tricky to manage all conditions. And does not always work as expected. 
I finally now use a `CDockablePane` and embed the CTestDlg. This workaround solve the visual style issue for modeless dialogs.